# Pandas Merge(): Appending data from merged columns and replace null values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I'd like to merge to tables while replacing the null value in one table with the non-null values from another.

The code below is an example of the tables to be merged:

```
# Table 1 (has rows with missing values)

a=['x','x','x','y','y','y']
b=['z', 'z', 'z' ,'w', 'w' ,'w' ]
c=[1,1,1,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]

table_1=pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})
table_1

    a   b   c
0   x   z   1.0
1   x   z   1.0
2   x   z   1.0
3   y   w   NaN
4   y   w   NaN
5   y   w   NaN

# Table 2 (new table to be appended to table_1, and would need to use values in column 'c' to replace values in the same column in table_1)

a=['y', 'y', 'y']
b=['w', 'w', 'w']
c=[2,2,2]
table_2=pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})
table_2

    a   b   c
0   y   w   2
1   y   w   2
2   y   w   2
```

This is the code I use for merging the 2 tables, and the ouput I get

```
# Merging the two tables

merged_table=pd.merge(table_1, table_2, on=['a', 'b'], how='left')
merged_table
```

Current output (I don't understand why the number of rows is increased):

```
    a   b   c_x c_y
0   x   z   1.0 NaN
1   x   z   1.0 NaN
2   x   z   1.0 NaN
3   y   w   NaN 2.0
4   y   w   NaN 2.0
5   y   w   NaN 2.0
6   y   w   NaN 2.0
7   y   w   NaN 2.0
8   y   w   NaN 2.0
9   y   w   NaN 2.0
10  y   w   NaN 2.0
11  y   w   NaN 2.0
```

Desired output (to replace the null values in the 'c' column in table_1 with the numeric values from table_2):

```
    a   b   c
0   x   z   1.0
1   x   z   1.0
2   x   z   1.0
3   y   w   2.0
4   y   w   2.0
5   y   w   2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
out=table_1.append(table_2).dropna(subset=['c']).reset_index(drop=True)
#OR
out=pd.concat([table_1,table_2]).dropna(subset=['c']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output of `out`:

```
    a   b   c
0   x   z   1.0
1   x   z   1.0
2   x   z   1.0
3   y   w   2.0
4   y   w   2.0
5   y   w   2.0
```

Comment: thanks @Anurag, it works as I need it to. Do you know what might be happening wit hthe extra rows when I initially merged the 2 tables?

Comment: @Pablo when you initialy merged the both df's then you can fill value of c_x with c_y then drop c_y and rename c_x